# Convert NSString in to NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, post

I'm using JSON POST approach, my code is

```
[_urlReq setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[_urlReq setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long) [postData length]];
[_urlReq setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[_urlReq setHTTPBody:postData];
_dataTask = [_urlSession dataTaskWithRequest:_urlReq  completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {

if (!(data == nil)) {
```

I'm converting response data in to string formate

```
NSString* myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];// NSUTF8StringEncoding
NSLog(@"myString :%@", myString);

OutPut:

myString :{"Response":{"status":"SUCCESS","error_code":"0","message":"message","Array":[{"name" => "VVV","name" => "CHE","ac" => "5a8805a","email" =>"vvv","line1" =>"","line2" =>"","no" =>"","street" =>"","pin_code" =>"","state_id" =>"0","district_name" =>"0"}]}}

//Convert string into Dic
NSData *data1 = [myString dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data1 options:0 error:nil];
NSLog(@"json : %@", json);
NSLog(@"Response : %@",[json objectForKey:@"Response"]);

//Second approach to convert string to dic
NSError *err = nil;
NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[myString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];
NSLog(@"array :%@", array);
NSDictionary *dictionary = [array objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"dictionary : %@", dictionary);
NSString *test = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Response"];
NSLog(@"Test is %@",test);                               

}
```

I don't know what is the problem here....

[image]

Comment: Did you check the error `err`?

Comment: I'm getting response from server like this myString :{"Response":{"status":"SUCCESS","error_code":"0","message":"message","Array":[{"name" => "VVV","name" => "CHE","ac" => "5a8805a","email" =>"vvv","line1" =>"","line2" =>"","no" =>"","street" =>"","pin_code" =>"","state_id" =>"0","district_name" =>"0"}]}}.  But when convert from String to Dic not getting any error

Comment: NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[myString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];
NSLog(@"array :%@", array);   ?? Y converting NSArray ??

Comment: Your json string is not valid. Please provide a valid json string.

Comment: @McDonal_1 Alredy I did this //Second approach to convert string to dic
NSError *err = nil;
NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[myString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];
NSLog(@"array :%@", array);

Comment: @  Boudhayan I'm getting this response when I convert from data to NSString   {"Response":{"status":"SUCCESS","error_code":"0","message":"message","Array":[{"name" => "VVV","name" => "CHE","ac" => "5a8805a","email" =>"vvv","line1" =>"","line2" =>"","no" =>"","street" =>"","pin_code" =>"","state_id" =>"0","district_name" =>"0"}]}}

Comment: The response is a JSON object not a string. You will have to parse the JSON directly.

Comment: your json string should be like this 

{"Response":{"status":"SUCCESS","error_code":"0","message":"message","Array":[{"name" : "VVV","name" : "CHE","ac" : "5a8805a","email" :"vvv","line1" :"","line2" :"","no" :"","street" :"","pin_code" :"","state_id" :"0","district_name" :"0"}]}}

Comment: @ hardik parmar Already I tried, when I parse directly it's getting null

Comment: Try Postman . How output will be ?

Comment: In ur response, TRY to CHANGE JSON from HTML in BOTTOM BAR..!!

Comment: I'm getting the sane out put

Comment: In postman, in RESPONSE area (bottom), that is in HTML format.  Change JSON format  from HTML format.

Comment: @McDonal_11 Yes, I did the same but I'm getting the same response. See the above question I updated

Answer (score 2):

You JSON format is Starting with Dictionary.

Instead of,

```
NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[myString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];
NSLog(@"array :%@", array);
```

Replace this and Try

```
NSDictionary *jSonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[myString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];
```

Second Try:

```
NSDictionary *jSonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];
```

For more info, how to validate JSON, use this link [enter link description here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com)

**Your JSON:**

[image]

Comment: I'm getting Null NSLog ("%@", jSonDict);

Comment: You can, directly, convert to Dictionary from data.

Comment: @ McDonal_11 No, when I convert from data to dic directly it's getting null.  When I convert from data to string only I'm getting this response {"Response":{"status":"SUCCESS","error_code":"0","message":"message","Array":[{"name" => "VVV","name" => "CHE","ac" => "5a8805a","email" =>"vvv","line1" =>"","line2" =>"","no" =>"","street" =>"","pin_code" =>"","state_id" =>"0","district_name" =>"0"}]}} Why I don't know

Comment: In post man I'm getting response like this {"Response":{"status":"SUCCESS","error_code":"0","message":"message","Array":[{"name" => "VVV","name" => "CHE","ac" => "5a8805a","email" =>"vvv","line1" =>"","line2" =>"","door_no" =>"","street" =>"","pin_code" =>"","state_id" =>"0","district_name" =>"0"}]}}

Comment: Can u post screenshot ? If possible ?

Comment: sorry for the late reply

Comment: After changing from json to Http also getting the same result

Answer (score 0):

Replace JSON response string with this

```
{"Response":{"status":"SUCCESS","error_code":"0","message":"message","Array":[{"name" : "VVV","name" : "CHE","ac" : "5a8805a","email" : "vvv","line1" : "","line2" : "","no" : "","street" : "","pin_code" : "","state_id" : "0","district_name" : "0"}]}}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your json string is not correct. Please check my demo json string.

**try this**

```
let myString :String = "{\"Response\":{\"status\":\"SUCCESS\",\"error_code\":\"0\",\"message\":\"message\",\"Array\":[{\"name\" : \"VVV\",\"name\" : \"CHE\",\"ac\" : \"5a8805a\",\"email\" :\"vvv\",\"line1\" :\"\",\"line2\" :\"\",\"no\" :\"\",\"street\" :\"\",\"pin_code\" :\"\",\"state_id\" :\"0\",\"district_name\" :\"0\"}]}}"

    if let data = myString.data(using: .utf8){
        do{
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .init(rawValue: 0));
            print(json)
        }catch{

        }

    }
```

**Output**

```
{
    Response =     {
        Array =         (
                        {
                ac = 5a8805a;
                "district_name" = 0;
                email = vvv;
                line1 = "";
                line2 = "";
                name = VVV;
                no = "";
                "pin_code" = "";
                "state_id" = 0;
                street = "";
            }
        );
        "error_code" = 0;
        message = message;
        status = SUCCESS;
    };
}
```